# matlab Floating point exception in libmwm_interpreter.so when using mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I developed a MEX-file for MATLAB, that I am using within an `ode45` solver.

```cpp
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    //enable floating point exception
    feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);

    size_t mrows,ncols;

    /* Check for proper number of arguments. */
    if(nrhs!=4) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:invalidNumInputs",
                "4 input required.");
    }
    if(nlhs>2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:invalidNumOutputs",
                "Too many output arguments");
    }

    /* The input must be a noncomplex scalar double.*/
    for(int i=0;i<nrhs;i++){
        mrows = mxGetM(prhs[i]);
        ncols = mxGetN(prhs[i]);
        if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[i]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[i]) ||
                !(mrows==1 && ncols==1) ) {
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:inputNotRealScalarDouble",
                    "Input must be a noncomplex scalar double.");
        }
    }

    /* Create matrix for the return argument. */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)mrows, (mwSize)ncols, mxREAL);

    /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
    const double t = *mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    const double p = *mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    const double T = *mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    const double U = *mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
    double& Thrust1 = *mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    Thrust1 = 9000;
    double Thrust;
    Foam::List<double> Mfr;

    try{
        MyFunction(t,p,T,U,Thrust,Mfr);
    }catch (std::exception& e){
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:error", e.what());
    }

    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)mrows, Mfr.size(), mxREAL);
    double* point = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
    for (mwSize i = 0; i < Mfr.size(); i++) {
        point[i] = 40; //Mfr[i];
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I detached the output of the MEX-file from the output of `MyFunction`, in order to exclude any problem in it, but the behavior was the following.

The MEX-file works well when called manually from MATLAB and also within very simple for loops. However when I call the `ode45` solver over a function that in turns calls this MEX-file I got the following error.

The interesting thing is that the error does not occur when the `ode45` calls the MEX-file the first time but at the second time.

Same behavior is produced when debugging in gdb, however no debug information is available since the source code of the MATLAB interpreter is not available.

My Matlab version is R2013a(8.1.0.604) 64-Bit(glnxa64)

#### MATLAB crash file:/home/trb12187/matlab_crash_dump.11254-1:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Floating point exception detected at Mon Sep  8 12:14:25 2014
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Current Visual     : 0x21 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding   : UTF-8
  GNU C Library      : 2.19 stable
  MATLAB Architecture: glnxa64
  MATLAB Root        : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
  Operating System   : Linux 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 30 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : The X.Org Foundation (11501000), display :0

Fault Count: 1

Abnormal termination:
Floating point exception

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000001  RBX = 00007fb110dda810
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 00007fb072653d70
  RSP = 00007fb110dda6c0  RBP = 00007fb110dda700
  RSI = 0000000000000001  RDI = 00007fb110dda810
   R8 = 0000000000000064   R9 = 0000000000000064
  R10 = 0000000000200000  R11 = 0000000000400000
  R12 = 0000000000000001  R13 = 00007fb072653d70
  R14 = 0000000000000000  R15 = 0000000000004000
  RIP = 00007fb123efeb2c  EFL = 0000000000010246
   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007fb123efeb2c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04434732
[  1] 0x00007fb123efe875 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04434037
[  2] 0x00007fb123f02645 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04449861
[  3] 0x00007fb123eecfd7 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04362199
[  4] 0x00007fb123eed950 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04364624
[  5] 0x00007fb123f347ec /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04655084
[  6] 0x00007fb123ef132f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+04379439
[  7] 0x00007fb123e7e204 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03908100
[  8] 0x00007fb123e80b76 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03918710
[  9] 0x00007fb123e80fac /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03919788
[ 10] 0x00007fb123c9d8ac /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01939628
[ 11] 0x00007fb123c99993 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01923475
[ 12] 0x00007fb123c9a797 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01927063
[ 13] 0x00007fb123d05e50 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02367056
[ 14] 0x00007fb12444a6b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866
        _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
[ 15] 0x00007fb123ce8256 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02245206
[ 16] 0x00007fb123c98a86 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01919622
[ 17] 0x00007fb123c9d374 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01938292
[ 18] 0x00007fb123c99993 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01923475
[ 19] 0x00007fb123c9a797 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01927063
[ 20] 0x00007fb123d05e50 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02367056
[ 21] 0x00007fb12444a6b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866
        _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
[ 22] 0x00007fb11b0f453a  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01672506
[ 23] 0x00007fb11b09513a  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01282362
[ 24] 0x00007fb11b0953be  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01283006
[ 25] 0x00007fb11b09712c  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+01290540
[ 26] 0x00007fb11b181f17  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcos.so+02252567
[ 27] 0x00007fb1243fcaf8 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00244472
        _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000488
[ 28] 0x00007fb123ce7d33 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02243891
[ 29] 0x00007fb123cf7798 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02307992
[ 30] 0x00007fb123cfb436 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02323510
[ 31] 0x00007fb123cfc54c /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02327884
[ 32] 0x00007fb123c7eb06 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01813254
[ 33] 0x00007fb123c75f28 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01777448
[ 34] 0x00007fb123c9e136 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01941814
[ 35] 0x00007fb123c99993 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01923475
[ 36] 0x00007fb123c9a797 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01927063
[ 37] 0x00007fb123d05e50 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02367056
[ 38] 0x00007fb12444a6b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866
        _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
[ 39] 0x00007fb123ce8256 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02245206
[ 40] 0x00007fb123c7409d /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01769629
[ 41] 0x00007fb123c9cb0e /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01936142
[ 42] 0x00007fb123c99993 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01923475
[ 43] 0x00007fb123c9a797 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01927063
[ 44] 0x00007fb123d05e50 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02367056
[ 45] 0x00007fb12444a6b2 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00562866
        _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000594
[ 46] 0x00007fb123cd4dcb /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+02166219
[ 47] 0x00007fb123c927cc /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01894348
[ 48] 0x00007fb123c8ee1d /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01879581
[ 49] 0x00007fb123c8f255 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+01880661
[ 50] 0x00007fb11ad44fae /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00139182
[ 51] 0x00007fb11ad45111 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00139537
[ 52] 0x00007fb11ad45ce5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00142565
        _Z8mnParserv+00000725
[ 53] 0x00007fb1246e23d2   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00447442
        _ZN11mcrInstance30mnParser_on_interpreter_threadEv+00000034
[ 54] 0x00007fb1246c19ac   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00313772
[ 55] 0x00007fb1246c1b88   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00314248
[ 56] 0x00007fb1182595c6   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00480710
[ 57] 0x00007fb118266df2   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00536050
[ 58] 0x00007fb124dac862 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01845346
[ 59] 0x00007fb124dad50f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01848591
        _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00001615
[ 60] 0x00007fb1246c25ef   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00316911
[ 61] 0x00007fb1246c2f5c   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00319324
[ 62] 0x00007fb1246bc592   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00292242
[ 63] 0x00007fb122850182              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00033154
[ 64] 0x00007fb12257cfbd                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01028029 clone+00000109
```

Thank you for your help, please let me know if you need more details to be posted.
Alessandro

Comment: Instead of answering your question *in* the question, consider posting this as a separate answer to maintain the question-answer format of stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: @alexmogavero: that's the purpose of `feenableexcept` (or the corresponding equivalent `_controlfp` in Windows), to raise hardware exception when certain floating-point errors occur (divide by zero, overflow/underflow, invalid operations like 0/0, etc..). You can trap these interrupts by writing a signal handler for `SIGFPE`, if you don't MATLAB will catch unhandled exceptions and generate a crash dump.

Comment: @Amro I solved as in the answer I posted. It seems to me that some operation in the MATLAB library generates floating point exception that are usually handled as NaN by MATLAB, that is why I have to disable them before moving to MATLAB routines. Please let me know if you have a more clever solution.

Comment: @alexmogavero: yep that's the idea, if you mess with the FPU flags, make sure to restore them before you return control to MATLAB...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, probably just the positive influence of Stackoverflow was enough for me.
Basically the issue is with the enabling of the floating point exception: `feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);` commenting out this line solved the problem. Probably this was affecting also the behaviour of the MATLAB interpreter, that could not handle the floating point exception as usual.
In order to keep the floating point exception enabled in my function (I do not want nan propagating through my code) I enabled and then disabled the floating point exception before and after the calling of `MyFunction`, so the final working version of the mex file is:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{

    size_t mrows,ncols;

    /* Check for proper number of arguments. */
    if(nrhs!=4) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:invalidNumInputs",
                "4 input required.");
    }
    if(nlhs>2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:invalidNumOutputs",
                "Too many output arguments");
    }

    /* The input must be a noncomplex scalar double.*/
    for(int i=0;i<nrhs;i++){
        mrows = mxGetM(prhs[i]);
        ncols = mxGetN(prhs[i]);
        if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[i]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[i]) ||
                !(mrows==1 && ncols==1) ) {
            mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:inputNotRealScalarDouble",
                    "Input must be a noncomplex scalar double.");
        }
    }

    /* Create matrix for the return argument. */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)mrows, (mwSize)ncols, mxREAL);

    /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
    const double t = *mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    const double p = *mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    const double T = *mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    const double U = *mxGetPr(prhs[3]);

    double& Thrust = *mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    Foam::List<double> Mfr;

    try{
        //enable floating point exception
        //it has to be disabled when exiting from this function!!
        feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
        MyFunction(t,p,T,U,Thrust,Mfr);
        fedisableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
    }catch (std::exception& e){
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "HYPRO:error", e.what());
    }

    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix((mwSize)mrows, Mfr.size(), mxREAL);
    double* point = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
    for (mwSize i = 0; i < Mfr.size(); i++) {
        point[i] = Mfr[i];
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your interest, I hope this can be of any help for others.

Alessandro